# How can I populate a GtkListStore with GdkPixbuf columns in Glade?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I'm working on a small PyGtk project that uses a GtkListStore to contain the data of the elements that I want to show as icons in a GtkIconView. I'm designing the UI with Glade.

I know how to add the data programmatically to the liststore. However, I've seen that that data can also be added in Glade directly.

I've managed to add columns, but I'm stuck at adding the rows of data for the GdkPixbuf column types. The image below should give some more detail.

What does Glade expect to be given in my 'icon' (GdkPixbuf) column? An absolute or relative path to a pixmap? Something else?

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image: GtkListStore definition in Glade]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but I've stumbled upon it and remembered I found the answer quite a while ago: Glade will take relative paths to images for GdkPixbuf fields, and will load the pixmap.